# How to make IN swing french doors OUT swing?

Tags: doors, patio

So I want to buy this french patio door for my she shed & its an IN swing.  I will need to buy a door frame and want the doors to swing OUT.  Is this something that can be done?  The doors are $80 for both. The man building the shed does custom work, but I dont want to cause tons of extra work/expense.  Suggestions?  I can DIY to an extent with good instructions, depending! :) Each door has 3 hinges on them that would attach to frame & each have a door knob near center and one has a twist latch/bolt in center.

Comment: Presumably this is a "prehung" door. It would not be easy to change the door from inward opening to outward opening because the door would have to be rehung. The hinges would have to be removed and flipped around. The doorstop would have to be removed and reinstalled.  Get a door which opens outward.

Comment: Thanks Jim, the doors did not come with a frame. I understand its just more trouble to make this door work for me. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4):

To do what you ask, is not a practical thing to do. First off, the inswing door panel is made differently than an outswing door since one has to be exposed to the weather directly and the other does not. Secondly the sill is configured differently too.

I have seen situations where an inswing door was simply turned around and set, removing the trim on the outside and setting back in place on the "new" outside. If this is done, it needs a small roof built over it to protect the top of the door and keep the weather from hitting the sill so rain does not simply roll in under the door

Comment: Thank you Jack, you saved me from a costly mistake!  Im just going to look for another door with a frame already.  Kind regards, Deb